# baffling cron thing on Raspberry Pi

Tags: cron

I am running a cron on a Pi. It basically works ... except .. that every now and again the system misbehaves and stops doing the scheduled things. When I log in to it I discover that the crontab has picked up a new line .....

The crontab looks like .....
 @reboot .... dum .. dee .. dum .. all works
 10 4-22 * * * do something else that works

but an extra line appears at the end

- - - - - /root/udevd > /dev/null 2>&1 &

and most of the rest stops running .... if I log in and comment this line out, things revert to normal operation.

any ideas what could make this happen?

Comment: Does the device have any ports that publically visible?

Comment: Um yes. It's on a cellular connection but uses an APN that allows inwards connections.  Deeper investigation revealed a repeated wget from a VERY strange URL. I think when I install the replacement card I won't use that APN again ... also the thing only spends about 5-10% of the time doing anything and I can take it offline between times ... I never heard of a Pi being hacked but I guess there's always a first time

Comment: Try setting the permissions on the cron file to 444. A lot of the references that came up when I searched for udevd and cron suggests a hack. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=udevd+cron&oq=udevd+cron&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.3230j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I also suggest installing a root kit hunter.

Comment: So here is what I have done.Make a new SD card. Use an APN that does not take inwards calls ie no public IP. Connect to the system using a VPN with AWS in the middle (or dataplicity). Disconnect for 90% of the time. If I have to do something I can send an email that stops the system disconnecting. NOW try and own me you suckers :-)

Comment: I am a bit of a newb here. How do I do that?

Comment: There should be an 'Answer your own question' at the bottom left of your screen ... when you are looking at this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Pi with a cell connection and a weak password. The cell connection permitted inwards calls.  I got owned ..... just like everyone says.

The use of an open link was not as bad as it sounds - the default mode of operation was to only connect for about two minutes in 20 and each time the IP address changed. Makes it a bit hard for the brute force probes to get far.

To fix it (using a new SD card). I used an APN that does not permit inwards connections. I communicate with the Pi using dataplicity or openvpn.